# How do I prevent Dropbox from being automatically added to the autostart list after launching it?

Tags: dropbox, autostart

Everytime I start Dropbox (in Precise) it gets added to the autostart list even if I deleted the entry before. I don't want Dropbox to be started when I log in only when I want it to.
How to prevent Dropbox to be automatically added to the autostart list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on the icon, preferences, then uncheck the box "Start Dropbox on system startup".

Comment: Oh my goodness, I totally overlooked this, after doing a fresh installation of Precise. Haha, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work with 17.10 and maybe even other recent versions.

Comment: That doesn't work because some very evil and/or stupid people work at  Dropbox. The checkbox is ignored; you have to use `dropbox autostart [ny]`

Comment: Tried everything, even `dropbox autostart n` not helped.. It's really ugly from Dropbox to make such mess :( only `sudo apt remove dropbox`finally  helped.. :/

Answer (score 16):

Command-line option might also work:

```
$ dropbox autostart n
```

---

From:

```
$ man dropbox
```

Comment: It fix the problem but if I start dropbox manually then it activate start on next reboot

Answer (score 2):

By default, dropbox will start automatically at login. 
The update-rc.d command is not concerned here. (/etc/rc*.d/directories don't contain dropbox). There is no service "dropbox"  (/etc/init.d don't contain dropbox)

If you have installed dropbox with ".deb" package (sudo dpkg -i dropbox.deb), then you may have the executable `/usr/bin/dropbox`

To disable the dropbox auto-start :

```
/usr/bin/dropbox autostart n
```

To enable the dropbox auto-start :

```
/usr/bin/dropbox autostart y
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me at Lubuntu 18.04, i3wm session. What I have done to fix that was:

1. Install Dropbox manually from the site www.dropbox.com/install

   32-bit:
   `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -`

   64-bit:
   `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -`
2. Use the official [python scrypt](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to manage Dropbox.