# 6 years later: how do we "still" prevent Dropbox from adding itself to autostart when launching it?

Tags: dropbox, autostart

I am aware of the [previous topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142131/how-do-i-prevent-dropbox-from-being-automatically-added-to-the-autostart-list-af?newreg=da364c44f7684970bd6904de71404d9b) (of 6 years ago), and of course I made sure that the **"Start Dropbox on system startup"** is unchecked in preferences...

**what I experience is:** 
I take it off from the autostart,
than I even reboot... 
and check: it's not in the autostart... still...

but then, I launch it, and it will be again in the autostart..
(it will be added when Dropbox exist, but this makes no difference)

I am certain that this is a bug in Dropbox...
but, too, I am certain that this bug is not really an accident...
there appears to be a persistent intention behind it :)

so, my question is how to prevent Dropbox from doing this...
I mean, by using our administrative rights to our system :) 
(and not by asking Dropbox, again and again stop doing this)

is it possible?
(using Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: bug reports are off-topic here.

Comment: seems to be a request for a workaround

Comment: @Zanna workarounds provided.

Comment: @jepe - I updated my workaround below with the final answer from dropbox. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

#### New Answer - August 2018

The issue can be resolved by a full reinstalled. Answer copied from [dropbox forums](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Unable-to-stop-autostart-on-Ubuntu/m-p/285134/highlight/true#M54915):

First, make sure you save and quit ALL programs that access files in the Dropbox folder.

Note: Please be sure to make a note or take a screenshot of any Selective Sync settings you may have applied as well as the location of your Dropbox folder (if not in the default location) prior to re-installing, as you will need to match these settings upon re-install. If you're using a headless version of Dropbox you can access the list of Selective Sync folders by running "dropbox exclude".

Depending on your OS and the package you used to perform the installation, you could have files in two different locations. I'm sending you instructions for both of the cases, so if some of the commands error out don't worry.

Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
dropbox stop
dropbox status # Should report "not running"
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
rm -rf ~/.dropbox*
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
rm /etc/apt/source.d/dropbox
```

Once you're done you have two options:

1. Install the Dropbox application with its graphical components using one of our packages. If you want to do that, download the correct package for your OS and architecture here:

   https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=linux

   Open your downloads folder and double click on the package file to start the installer.

   When Dropbox has finished installing, please sign in and apply any Selective Sync settings you may have had prior to the reinstall and select the Dropbox folder location (if not in the default location) during the sign in process. Your account will take a few moments to reindex the files and sync any pending changes.
2. The second option is to run a headless version of Dropbox. This version will not have any of the menus or graphical components and can only be interacted with through the command line. To install this version do the following:

   If your machine is 32-bit:

   ```
   cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
   ```

   If your machine is 64-bit:

   ```
   cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
   ```

   Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

   ```
   ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
   ```

   When Dropbox has finished installing please sign in and apply any Selective Sync settings you may have had prior to the reinstall. Your account will take a few moments to reindex the files and sync any pending changes.

More installation and CLI information is also available here:

https://www.dropbox.com/install

Once that's done, please open the preferences of the application, (via right clicking the tray icon), and in the Accounts tab of preferences, untick "Start Dropbox on system Startup".

---

#### Old work-around

This behaviour only appeared around a month or two ago, so I believe this is a bug and I have reported it to Dropbox.

The only workaround I have found is to:

1. Quit Dropbox
2. Open up Ubuntu Startup Applications Preferences
3. Remove Dropbox from the list

Alternatively, you could type this command in a terminal:

```
dropbox autostart n
```

Both these options need to be done after each time you run Dropbox.

If this is really annoying you, you can try editing or locking-down the Dropbox autostart file directly, but be mindful of unintended consequences. You can find it here:

```
~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious, but when I got annoyed with the dropbox client autostarting I simply uninstalled it. Since I didn't purge it I still have the original `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` on my system: Mine looks like this.

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

Now if I had still wanted to use it (I didn't and uninstalled it). I would simply move the launcher from autostart to the desktop. with the command `mv ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/Desktop/` This is a simple hack and since the launcher is no longer in the autostart folder it shouldn't be automatically started.

If for some reason that doesn't work because the entry is getting erroneously recreated due to non-existence you could simply edit the file changing the `Exec=dropbox start -i` line to `Exec=dropbox running` which just returns 1 if running and 0 if not and does not run the dropbox daemon.

You could also be extremely insistent about your demands if the launcher is getting overwritten with defaults by simply removing permissions to access ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop by making it either impossible to read at login or impossible to overwrite. For this brutal hack see `man chmod`

**Sources:**

`~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` on my system

https://linux.die.net/man/1/dropbox